# How to format code with ctrl + alt + l in Android Studio to keep statements without braces on the same line?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

**Here is the default code when press "ctrl + alt + l":**

```
if(...)
  Log.w("...", "...");

else if(...)
  Log.w("...", "...");

else
  Log.w("...", "...");

for(...)
  Log.w("...", "...");

while(...)
  Log.w("...", "...");

etc...
```

**I want when I press "ctrl + alt + l", for anything without braces to be put on the same line as the statement. Here is what I am looking for when I press "ctrl + alt + l":**

```
if(...) Log.w("...", "...");

else if(...) Log.w("...", "...");

else Log.w("...", "...");

for(...) Log.w("...", "...");

while(...) Log.w("...", "...");

etc...
```

How can I achieve this in Android Studio?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure 'Keep when reformatting' > 'Line breaks' is disabled.
And enable the 'Control statement in one line' option from File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | Java | 'Wrapping and Braces'.
See: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/7028031675026-if-statement-on-one-line

Comment: Not work with me